# Is a holomorphic Function of a matrix invertible?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory, functional-calculus

I am currently reading a Paper and I don't quite get one part. The Paper is about Function of matrices and in one part he says:

> "Since $g(z)$ is a holomorphic function on $\Omega$ and never vanishes, $g(A)$ must be invertible" (for some open $\Omega$ that contains the spectrum of $A$ and a linear bounded operator $A$)

I understand that since $g(z)$ never vanishes $h(z):=\frac{1}{g(z)}$ must also be holomorphic and therefor $h(A)$ exists. But how do I know that $h(A)$ is actually equal to $g(A)^{-1}$?

Comment: The answer is likely buried in your understanding of what $g(A)$ is.  Aspects of this statement suggest that you understand that there is a map $f \mapsto f(A)$ (where $f$ is holomorphic on an open set containing the spectrum of $A$). This map happens to be an algebra homomorphism, so if $g(z) h(z) = 1$ for all $z$ in that set, one will also have $g(A) h(A) = I$, which has the consequence that you want. The details depend on how you define that map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this theorem in spectral theory that says (if $g$ is continuous and defined on the spectrum of linear bounded $A$)
$$
\sigma(g(A)) = g(\sigma(A)).
$$
$\sigma$ of course denotes the spectrum. Since $g$ does not vanish, $0$ cannot be in the spectrum of $g(A)$. It follows that $g(A)$ is invertible.